# How are objects created for FileOutputStream

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, internal-storage

I am a beginner in android also in Java, many times I get confused with various Java implementations in android one of them is:
In the statements

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

what is fos in the above statement? It is obviously object of fileOutputStream but why is it not implemented as

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If possible give me a simple example in java/android.

Answer (score 1):

`openFileOutput` is a method of the `Context` that automatically creates a file output stream to your context's data folder.

If you use the constructor of `FileOutputStream`, you have to pass a full file path as the first argument, while the `Context` takes only the file name. For files that need not be accessible via file managers, use `openFileOutput` for saving the file and `openFileInput` for reading the file again.